How to prevent quectel EC25E device Initialize in 2G/3G mood
While working with quectel EC25E device. When i insert sim into the device i found following logs from
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 (Since i have 8 port device and i have inserted sim on port 0)
I found following log
+CFUN: 1                                                                        
                                                                                
+CPIN: READY                                                                    
                                                                                
+QUSIM: 1                                                                       
                                                                                
+QIND: SMS DONE                                                                 
                                                                                
+QIND: PB DONE                                                                  
                                                                                
RDY                                                                             
                                                                                
+CFUN: 1                                                                        
                                                                                
+CPIN: READY                                                                    
                                                                                
+QUSIM: 1                                                                       
                                                                                
+QIND: SMS DONE                                                                 
                                                                                
+QIND: PB DONE                                                                  
                                                                                
RDY                                                                             
                                                                                
+CFUN: 1                                                                        
                                                                                
+CPIN: READY                                                                    
                                                                                
+QUSIM: 1                                                                       
                                                                                
+QIND: SMS DONE                                                                 
                                                                                
+QIND: PB DONE                                                                  
                                                                                
RDY                                                                             
                                                                                
+CFUN: 1                                                                        
                                                                                
+CPIN: READY                                                                    
                                                                                
+QUSIM: 1                                                                       
                                                                                
+QIND: SMS DONE                                                                 
                                                                                
+QIND: PB DONE                                                                  
                                                                                
+CTZE: "+24",0,"2024/05/06,11:35:47"                                            
                                                                                
+CTZE: "+24",0,"2024/05/06,11:35:50"

The log is telling me it's restaring and searchinf for network.
Later on i confirm it by following command
AT+CREG
output : 0,1 Which means it found the network and registerd within the netowrk for the sim operator.
I am looking forward to find a way to make sure my device always work within network 2g/3g network because i am dealing with USSD operation so i dont 4G neither internet connect.
